# Background grid in QGraphicsView is rendered incorrectly when zooming

Tags: qgraphicsview, pyside6, qt6

I'm trying to draw a background grid for a QGraphicsView by setting the background brush to a QPixmap showing the upper and right side of a square - this works well and all, but in conjunction with a simple zoom functionality using the wheelEvent and scaleView(), the grid is rendered with parts missing, or not all, when zooming out.

Below a minimal example:

```py
import math

from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene
from PySide6.QtGui import QPixmap, QPainter
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt, QRectF
    
class CanvasView(QGraphicsView):

    class CanvasScene(QGraphicsScene):
        def __init__(self, canvas_view, initial_width, initial_height):
            QGraphicsScene.__init__(self, canvas_view)

    def __init__(self, initial_width, initial_height, grid_step):
        QGraphicsView.__init__(self)
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, initial_width, initial_height)
        self.canvas_scene = self.CanvasScene(self, initial_width, initial_height)
        self.setScene(self.canvas_scene)

        # draw grid

        self.grid_cell = QPixmap(grid_step, grid_step)
        self.grid_cell.fill(Qt.transparent)

        self.cell_painter = QPainter(self.grid_cell)
        self.cell_painter.setPen(Qt.lightGray)
        self.cell_painter.drawLine(0, 0, self.grid_cell.width() - 1, 0)
        self.cell_painter.drawLine(0, 0, 0, self.grid_cell.width() - 1)

        self.setBackgroundBrush(self.grid_cell)

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        self.scaleView(math.pow(2.0, event.angleDelta().y() / 240.0))

    def scaleView(self, scaleFactor):
        factor = self.transform().scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor).mapRect(QRectF(0, 0, 1, 1)).width()
        if factor < 0.07 or factor > 100:
            return
        self.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor)

app = QApplication()
view = CanvasView(1000, 500, 20)
view.show()

app.exec()
```

And here some screenshots showing the incorrect grid rendering:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Happens on both Linux and Windows. Does anyone have a clue why this happens and how to fix so that the grid scales correctly?

Comment: @G.M. It is complete, it was just bad indentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the fact that the brush based on a pixmap, which being a raster image, it's pixel-based.

Scaling raster images that contain straight lines results in [*aliasing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing), as shown in the wikipedia examples.

The source image:

[image: high resolution image with straight lines]

And the scaled image, without proper anti-aliasing filters:

[image: small resolution with aliasing]

Considering this, using a pixmap based brush is obviously not a valid option.

Even the `Antialiasing` render hint can't do much about this.

Instead, you can override [`drawBackground()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#drawBackground) and paint the grid from there, using QPainter drawing functions.

```py
class CanvasView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, initial_width, initial_height, grid_step):
        QGraphicsView.__init__(self)
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, initial_width, initial_height)
        self.canvas_scene = CanvasScene(self, initial_width, initial_height)
        self.setScene(self.canvas_scene)
        self.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

        self.grid_step = grid_step
        self.grid_pen = QPen(Qt.lightGray)

    def drawBackground(self, qp, rect):
        qp.translate(.5, .5)
        qp.setPen(self.grid_pen)

        x, y, right, bottom = rect.toRect().getCoords()
        top = y
        left = x
        step = self.grid_step

        yrest = y % step
        if yrest:
            y += step - yrest
        for y in range(y, bottom, step):
            qp.drawLine(left, y, right, y)

        xrest = x % step
        if xrest:
            x += step - xrest
        for x in range(x, right, step):
            qp.drawLine(x, top, x, bottom)
```

On my 10y old computer, with the given window size and at the minimum zoom value, it takes less than 30ms to draw the whole scene (~850 lines).

If the scene rect is fixed, some further improvement could be achieved by pre-computing the whole grid in a QPicture and just draw it instead of doing it every time.

Comment: Thanks, I adopted your solution even though I wanted to avoid drawing the grid explicitly - unfortunately, my scene rect is not fixed but performance-wise there should be no problem anyway.